Finite type ring homomorphisms and finitely many localizations
Let $\phi : B \to A$ be a homomorphism of commutative rings with identity. Let $f_1, \ldots, f_n$ be elements of $A$, such that $(f_1, \ldots, f_n) = (1)$.
I want to prove that if each of the localizations $B \to A_{f_i}$ is of finite type, than so is $B \to A$.
I know that similar questions have been asked before on this site, but I was not able use them to deduce an answer (this is essentially the claim that the property of being a locally of finite type morphism of schemes is affine local on the target).
For simplicity, suppose that $A$ is an integral domain. Then $A$ embeds into $A_{f_i}$, and the assumptions ensure that there are elements $g_1, \ldots, g_m$ in $A$, such that every element
$a \in A$ satisfies equations of the form $af_i^{M_i} = p_i(g_1, \ldots, g_m)$ for each $i$, where $M$ is an integer and $p$ is a polynomial with $\phi(B)$ coefficients (both depending on $a$ and $i$).
The goal is to find such an equation for $a$ itself.
My main idea was to use the fact that $(f_i^{M_i} \;:\; i = 1, \ldots n) = (1)$ holds, so that I can combine the above equations into a single equation for $a$:
$a = \sum_i c_ip_i(g_1, \ldots, g_n)$, where $1 = \sum c_i f_i^{M_i}$. However, I have no control over the coefficients $c_i$. In particular, I can not ensure that they belong to $\phi(B)$.
How do I proceed?
